# React Native app is closing as soon as I open

Tags: android, react-native, logcat

**React native info**

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.6.4
    CPU: (8) x64 Apple M2
    Memory: 35.99 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.19.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.21 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 10.2.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2024.01.22.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.15.2 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 23.2, iOS 17.2, macOS 14.2, tvOS 17.2, visionOS 1.0, watchOS 10.2
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2023.2 AI-232.10227.8.2321.11479570
    Xcode: 15.2/15C500b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.21 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    react-native: 0.68.4 => 0.68.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

App is running on IOS devices. When I try to run the app for android, build is successful but when I open the app it is closing instantly. This is the log I'm getting in logcat when I try to open the app. No logs on the react native console.
I can't attach the full logs here, so here is the link for the log file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ut8-dEupzgKXJapbIW8fLzw1cmgkVqn5/view?usp=sharing

This is the log I got when I ran **adb logcat --buffer=crash**:

```
03-20 12:08:05.477 15718 15792 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x773193e5a3 in tid 15792 (FlipperEventBas), pid 15718 (com.nalanative)
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_arm64/emulator64_arm64:12/SE1A.220203.002.A1/8151367:user/release-keys'
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2024-03-20 12:08:05.518502497+0530
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : Process uptime: 0s
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : Cmdline: com.nalanative
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : pid: 15718, tid: 15792, name: FlipperEventBas  >>> com.nalanative <<<
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : uid: 10147
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x773193e5a3
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :     x0  00000075d95fc938  x1  0000000000000090  x2  0000000000000001  x3  b40000770191d090
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :     x4  00000075d95fca90  x5  00000075d95fba70  x6  0000000000000000  x7  00000000ebad808b
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :     x8  940000773193e5a3  x9  0000000000000090  x10 b4000076b1987d99  x11 b4000076b1987d91
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000000000000  x14 000000000000000c  x15 000000000000000c
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000000000000010  x17 0000000000000010  x18 00000075d8fa8000  x19 00000075d95fc9b0
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :     x20 b40000770191d090  x21 00000075d95fe000  x22 ffffff8a26a01fff  x23 00000075d95fca90
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :     x24 00000075d95fe000  x25 00000075d95fd0b8  x26 0000000000000001  x27 00000075d95fd208
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000000000000000  x29 00000075d95fc8e0
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :     lr  00000075db7badcc  sp  00000075d95fc8e0  pc  00000075db7bb730  pst 0000000060001000
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 00000000000af730  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libc++_shared.so (BuildId: ece72a2ebc3774a1be9fd21271258acd3bcdfaa7)
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00000000000aedc8  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libc++_shared.so (BuildId: ece72a2ebc3774a1be9fd21271258acd3bcdfaa7)
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 00000000000aebf8  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libc++_shared.so (__gxx_personality_v0+200) (BuildId: ece72a2ebc3774a1be9fd21271258acd3bcdfaa7)
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00000000000b9640  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (unwind_phase2+156) (BuildId: ba489d4985c0cf173209da67405662f9)
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00000000000b96f8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (_Unwind_Resume+52) (BuildId: ba489d4985c0cf173209da67405662f9)
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00000000001a0ae4  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so (folly::Future<std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<rsocket::RSocketClient, std::__ndk1::default_delete<rsocket::RSocketClient> > >::get() &&+316) (BuildId: 9b092ff8953cb8772583f7c3461ee023ad5c43cf)
03-20 12:08:05.914 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 000000000019d994  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so (facebook::flipper::FlipperConnectionManagerImpl::doCertificateExchange()+2084) (BuildId: 9b092ff8953cb8772583f7c3461ee023ad5c43cf)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 000000000019c844  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so (facebook::flipper::FlipperConnectionManagerImpl::startSync()+380) (BuildId: 9b092ff8953cb8772583f7c3461ee023ad5c43cf)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 00000000001abe44  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so (BuildId: 9b092ff8953cb8772583f7c3461ee023ad5c43cf)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 00000000001a7e74  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so (void folly::detail::function::FunctionTraits<void ()>::callSmall<void folly::Executor::KeepAlive<folly::Executor>::add<folly::futures::detail::Core<folly::Unit>::doCallback(folly::Executor::KeepAlive<folly::Executor>&&, folly::futures::detail::State)::'lambda'(folly::Executor::KeepAlive<folly::Executor>&&)>(folly::futures::detail::Core<folly::Unit>::doCallback(folly::Executor::KeepAlive<folly::Executor>&&, folly::futures::detail::State)::'lambda'(folly::Executor::KeepAlive<folly::Executor>&&)&&) &&::'lambda'()>(folly::detail::function::Data&)+76) (BuildId: 9b092ff8953cb8772583f7c3461ee023ad5c43cf)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 000000000023e824  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so (folly::EventBase::FunctionLoopCallback::runLoopCallback()+24) (BuildId: 9b092ff8953cb8772583f7c3461ee023ad5c43cf)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 000000000023a638  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so (folly::EventBase::runLoopCallbacks()+196) (BuildId: 9b092ff8953cb8772583f7c3461ee023ad5c43cf)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 000000000023b434  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so (folly::EventBase::loopBody(int, bool)+736) (BuildId: 9b092ff8953cb8772583f7c3461ee023ad5c43cf)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 000000000023c434  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so (folly::EventBase::loopForever()+36) (BuildId: 9b092ff8953cb8772583f7c3461ee023ad5c43cf)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 000000000018df58  /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so (BuildId: 9b092ff8953cb8772583f7c3461ee023ad5c43cf)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 0000000000222244  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148) (BuildId: e6c658201ef1ec3760112fa1b838ab2c)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 0000000000212520  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+4016) (BuildId: e6c658201ef1ec3760112fa1b838ab2c)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 000000000034bc44  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~AruxQF5h8QvZKfeMEkeQcg==/com.nalanative-Sh_IGdhPo2f0jpJgcDxy6w==/base.apk]
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 0000000000218964  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: e6c658201ef1ec3760112fa1b838ab2c)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 0000000000284208  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+188) (BuildId: e6c658201ef1ec3760112fa1b838ab2c)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #20 pc 000000000061fb98  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+460) (BuildId: e6c658201ef1ec3760112fa1b838ab2c)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #21 pc 000000000066e75c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1184) (BuildId: e6c658201ef1ec3760112fa1b838ab2c)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #22 pc 00000000000b1910  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+264) (BuildId: ba489d4985c0cf173209da67405662f9)
03-20 12:08:05.915 15813 15813 F DEBUG   :       #23 pc 00000000000513f0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: ba489d4985c0cf173209da67405662f9)
```

Comment: Include log in your question

Comment: If no logs appear on react native console. Try using `adb logcat --buffer=crash` for Android app

Comment: I tried including logs in question itself, apparently there is a limit for characters in questions. I can't include whole log, so I have added a link to the log file

Comment: That's fine. You usually do not need a whole log. Only some top entries are relevant while some down the line may be just a consequence of the former issue and will be gone once it's fixed